# Is it possible to to create an instance of an object with WPF controls without explicitly setting all of the control texts to object property?

Tags: c#, database, wpf-controls

I have a wpf form with a bunch of Textbox input controls.
I have an object for which I want to make an instance using the text from the controls.

I have a button that I would like to have trigger the creation of an instance of the object when pushed.

Is there any way to do this without manually setting each object.property = textbox.text ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, look at MVVM and explicitly MVVM Light.  If you have a pluralsite account, there are some great courses on it.  ~cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into MVVM pattern.

Basically you have UI and a ViewModel bind together

For example: in UI you have button1 and button2.

You have property text1 and text2 in your VM.

You have data binding between button1.Text to text1 property in the VM. This can be bidirectional data binding so when the text in the button1 changed the value of text1 also changed.

I use caliburn micro and very simple and straight forward but any MVVM framework will do. MVVMLight or Prism to name a few